# Use existing unwind segue from another action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, unwind-segue

I have two buttons - "Ok" and "Delete", and the "Ok" unwinds the segue to the last ViewController.

I want the "Delete" button to fire up the same unwind segue, but to do some action beforehand. (In my case, delete info from Firebase).

How can I combine both an action and unwind segue ? I tried calling PerformSegueWithIdentifier function but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second *unwind segue* by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from your <kbd>Delete</kbd> button to the *Exit* icon.  You can even use the existing `@IBAction` in your destination viewController.  Give this segue an identifier (select the segue in the *Document Outline* view and set the identifier in the *Attributes Inspector*) such as `"deleteSegue"` and then in `prepare(for:sender)` check for the identifier and  delete the info from Firebase.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "deleteSegue" {
        // delete data from Firebase
    }
}
```

---

Follow up question from the comments:

> I want to perform an action BEFORE unwinding the segue - I want a
>   popup to ask the user if he really wants to delete the item. only
>   after that I want the item deleted and segue unwinded.

Instead of wiring the unwind segue from the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button, wire it from the *viewController* icon at the top of the VC to the *Exit* icon. Still give it the identifier and then call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "deleteSegue", sender: self)` when you want to perform the segue.

Comment: I will try this in a moment, I just encountered a fatal bug I'm trying to debug. I deleted a .swift file, and changed a view's class from the deleted file to a different one, and I see it crashes when loading that view... Any ideas what's causing it ?

Comment: Could be you are missing an outlet connect.  Check the console for a message.  You might want to add an Exception breakpoint in the Breakpoint Inspector.

Comment: I need to learn to use the debug console :) I'm rather new to Xcode so I'm learning the debugging ropes yet.  I forgot to give my UICollectionViewCell an identifier. Whoops ! Fixed now :) Let me try your solution to my problem

Comment: Ok I read your solution again, and there is a problem. I want to perform an action BEFORE unwinding the segue - I want a popup to ask the user if he really wants to delete the item. only after that I want the item deleted and segue unwinded.

Comment: Instead of wiring the *unwind segue* from the Delete button, wire it from the viewController icon at the top of the VC to the exit icon.  Still give it the identifier and then call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "deleteSegue", sender: self)` when you want to perform the segue.